# Error while importing .sql file in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Getting error while importing `.sql` file in phpMyAdmin please help.

```
Error
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE  `sbbleads_admin` (
 `sb_id` BIGINT( 20 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `sb_admin_name` VARCHAR( 255 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `sb_pwd` VARCHAR( 255 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (  `sb_id` )
) TYPE = MYISAM ;
```

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 6

Answer (score 2):

`TYPE` should be `ENGINE`

```
CREATE TABLE  `sbbleads_admin` (
 `sb_id` BIGINT( 20 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `sb_admin_name` VARCHAR( 255 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `sb_pwd` VARCHAR( 255 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (  `sb_id` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```